# apigateway body mapping template not working from s3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mapping, aws-api-gateway

I have a react app in an s3 bucket that is connected via apigateway to a serverless python backend on lambda.

When I test the lambda function from the API gateway it works great. However, when I invoke the API from the website it doesn't run through the body mapping template and the lambda just receives what the website sends without processing it through the template first. Why is this?

This is the body mapping template:

```
{"api_name" : "$context.resourcePath","http-method" :"$context.httpMethod","body" :$input.json('$')}
```

Comment: I do not have a straightforward reason for this behavior. As a starting point, I would enable detailed CloudWatch logs in API Gateway (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/) and send request from the react app and then send another request to the API via curl. Then I would compare the difference between the CloudWatch logs the two requests. I hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: I echo the comment above in that some actual tests and results would go a long way to helping figure out what the problem is here. The only thing that I am aware of that will change whether the mapping templates are used or not is the content-type header. Testing in the API Gateway will sometimes automatically set this header to application/json, but you would need to set it yourself when making the call from the website.